# Как дать доступ к socket-серверу для неавторизованного юзера?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, jwt

Делаю чат на React и использую на сервере socket.io-jwt (https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-socketio-jwt) для авторизации.

Проблема в том, что неавторизованному юзеру не удается получить доступ к серверу и загрузить сообщения с сервера т.к с клиента не отправляется jwt-token. Может кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой?

```
const io = require('socket.io')()
const socketioJwt = require('socketio-jwt')
const onlineUsers = []
const messages = []
io.sockets.use(socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: 'secret',
    handshake: true,
    required: false
}))
io.sockets
    .on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log(`Connected user: ${socket.decoded_token.id}`)
        socket.emit('authenticated', {
            message: 'Connected'
        })
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`Disconnected user: ${socket.decoded_token.id}`)
        })
    })
    .on('unauthorized', (socket) => {
        console.log(`Unauthorized user: ${socket}`)
    });
io.listen(9000);
```

Сама авторизация через passport

Comment: сгенерируйте гостевой токен

Comment: @InDevX, т.е создать в базе юзера типа "гость" и генерировать токен для него?

Comment: Да, это самый простой варииант. Покажите серверный код

Comment: @InDevX добавил код, сама авторизация через passport jwt

Comment: Не скажу что идеальный вариант, но самый простой и точно рабочий вариант (если у вас ничего особого за токеном не подтягивается, ибо гостей куча может быть, а токен общий для всех)